# Import-Module AWSPowerShell taking 30 seconds on EC2 instance - how to reduce?

Tags: powershell, aws-powershell

I have a powershell script that runs on an EC2 t2.medium instance, but the script is taking 30 seconds just to import the AWSPowershell module.

I've tried importing only the cmdlets that I need, but it made no difference in load time.

Is it possible to reduce this in any way?

Comment: Any idea on what the server load is like? In my past experience this issue occurs on busy systems or when the virtual host is under heavy load.

Comment: Almost no load. Tried on a few boxes with more load and all took around the same time. Locally it runs in a couple seconds, so it may just be related to the box specs.

Comment: Which PowerShell version do you use? Try PowerShell 5.0 and try using module statement.